# Relation between Youngs Modulus and Co-efficient Of resistitution

Tags: collision, material-science, elasticity

I was thinking that $Y$ (youngs modulus) should be dependent on $e$ (Co-efficient of Restitution) as COR explains the separation/approaching ratios of velocities of 2 objects colliding, The velocity after collision depends on the material of both the objects. According to me, it is the deformation that comes back (Sorry, this description is informal, I am trying to express it how i think and where i might go wrong). For COR less than 1, some Potential energy is stored in the object as deformation. Hence, the Net Kinetic energy decreases. This makes me think cor should be dependent on both $Y$ of the the objects in collision. I am trying to get a relation. (I might be wrong in my thinking, if so please direct me in the correct direction and sorry for any grammatical mistakes I make.)